# Как в Symfony 4 использовать бизнес логику?

Tags: symfony4

Изучал Symfony Forms. Практически все завязано на валидации объектов. Возник вопрос как оперировать бизнес правилами? Например, в голову приходит опыт ранней разработки на сыром php.

```
$error = [];
if (false) $error[] = "Ошибка ввода";
if (!$error) { // save/redirect }
// Далее допустим html
// print $error
```

Как эта ситуация решается на фреймворке?
UPD. Под правилами я понимаю обработку логики приложения. То есть неважно как выглядит сущность (за это отвечает constraint). Например, как создать новую запись на основе нескольких объектов? Для успеха надо проверить user.balance > item.price, накопить историю этих проверок и вывести собщение/ошибки..Возможно надо подтягивать сюда сессии, временные параметры, конфигурацию..
Все это выполняют сервисы. Интересна сама реализация.

Comment: Что подразумевается под бизнес-правилом?

Comment: Создаете контроллер, в экшен прокидываете реквест и нужные сервисы, обрабатываете данные, возвращаете респонс. Можно сделать так называемый "толстый контроллер" и не прокидывать в него сервисы, а все описать всю логику прямо в экшене контроллера.

Comment: То есть магии нет? Я просто беру и процедурно пишу свою систему как раньше? Без всяких violation, слушателей и прочего

Comment: Какую вы хотите магию? Не очень понятно. Взаимодействие с вебом (и с симфони) описывается в рамках реквест-респонс (получили реквест, обработали, вернули респонс). Обработчик реквеста соответственно реализуете вы сами.

Comment: Я же написал вначале. Что используя формы имеется большой инструментарии и правила обработки. Для операции с логикой ничего не нашел, поэтому создал вопрос. В итоге мне самому надо "изобретать" механизм.

Comment: Компонент форм генерирует формы и сохраняет данные форм в какой-то понятный вид для дальнейшего использования. Он знать не знает ни про какие-то БД, бизнес-логики и прочее. Поэтому вы встраиваете его в свою бизнес-логику. Получили данные с формы - хотите сохраняйте как-то в БД, хотите шлите письмом, компоненту форм все равно.